# Multiple terms filter is not working on elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using elastic search 2.2.0 and I am new in it. I want to search result using two filters but it shows me fatal error: query does not support multiple fields.

Two filters are:

```
plocation: china
pcategoryid: 0,20,21
```

Here is my code:

```
$search = 'Doors';
$limit = 6;
$params = [
    'index' => 'product',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            "bool" => [
                "should" => [
                    'multi_match' => [
                        "fields" => [
                            "pname",
                            "pmodel",
                            "pcategoryname",
                            "pmetakeyword"
                        ],
                        "query" => $search,
                        "type" => "phrase",
                        "boost" => 10
                    ],
                    'multi_match' => [
                        "fields" => [
                            "pname",
                            "pmodel",
                            "pcategoryname",
                            "pmetakeyword"
                        ],
                        "query" => $search,
                        "type" => "most_fields",
                        "fuzziness" => "1",
                        "boost" => 0
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ],

        "filter" => [
            "bool" => [
                "must" => [
                    "term" => [
                        "ptypeid" => 1
                    ]
                ],
                "should" => [
                    "term" => [
                        "psearchstatus" => 1
                    ]
                ],
                "filter" => [
                    "terms" => [
                        "plocation" => ['china'], "pcategoryid" => [0,20,21]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ],
        "from" => ($page - 1) * $limit,
        "size" => $limit
    ],
];
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$response = $client->search($params);
$results = $response['hits']['hits'];
```

Is there another way to go about what I'm attempting to do, or am I on the right track?

Comment: please provide also the structure of your index/type

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the [`terms` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) that you are attempting to apply. Like the `term` filters above it, it only accepts a single field, but with an array of values.

```
"terms" => [
  "plocation" => ['china'], "pcategoryid" => [0,20,21]
]
```

should be

```
"terms" => [
  "plocation" => ['china']
],
"terms" => [
  "pcategoryid" => [0,20,21]
]
```

Comment: No idea why this was drive-by downvoted, but this is the issue.